# Does $\forall X \in L_{\kappa}: P(X) \subset L_{\kappa}$ hold in $L$

Tags: set-theory, constructibility

While working on an exercise in Jech's *Set Theory*, I tried to prove that if $V=L$, then $\forall X \in L_{\kappa}: P(X) \subset L_{\kappa}$, where $k$ is any cardinal.  I was hoping someone could verify that this is true, or else help me find the error in my argument.

PROOF:  Let $Y \subset X \in L_{\kappa}$.  Then, $X \in L_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha < \kappa$.  Since $V=L$, $Y \in L_{\gamma}$ for some limit ordinal $\gamma \geq \alpha$.  We can find an elementary substructure $M \prec L_{\gamma}$ s.t. $Y \in M$, $L_{\alpha} \subset M$ and $|M|<k$.  Let $\pi$ be the transitive collapsing function on $M$; then $\pi[M]=L_{\beta}$ by the condensation lemma.  Therefore, $|\beta|=|L_{\beta}|=|M|<\kappa$, so $\beta < \kappa$ and $L_{\beta} \subset L_{\kappa}$.  Since $L_{\alpha}$ is a transitive subset of $M$, it can be shown (by $\in$-induction on the elements of $L_{\alpha}$) that $\pi$ is the identity on $L_{\alpha}$.  Since, $Y \subset L_{\alpha}$, $Y=\pi(Y) \in L_{\beta}$.  Thus, $Y \in L_{\kappa}$.  By generality of $Y$, $P(X) \subset L_{\kappa}$.

Comment: Your proof is fine, except that in the proof you are assuming $\kappa$ is infinite. But the statement is true even when $\kappa$ is a finite cardinal. So you could simply handle the case of finite $\kappa$ separately.

Comment: You are assuming that $\kappa$ is a *cardinal*. This is not true for arbitrary ordinals.

Comment: Andres, he states clearly that $\kappa$ is "any cardinal".  In the proof, he is assuming that $\kappa$ is an *infinite* cardinal, since when $\kappa$ is a finite cardinal, you can't get $X\in L_\alpha$ for some $\alpha<\kappa$, and you can't get $|M|<\kappa$ etc. But the proof is fine provided that $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Yes, I know. This was a comment for Ari to think about, not a critique of the argument; things really get interesting when one tries to see what one can say when $\kappa$ is just an ordinal. (By the way, I was hoping you'd post the slides of your public talk. If not, could you please email me a copy?)

Comment: Oh, they are posted on my web page, see the Slides link at the bottom of http://jdh.hamkins.org/higher-infinity-and-the-foundations-of-mathematics-aaas-2014/, and I also shared them on Google+.

Comment: @Andres, why don't you post an answer concerning some of that interesting stuff you allude to, as a way of bringing this question to a resolution?

Comment: (@JoelDavidHamkins Ah, how silly! I don't know how I didn't see it, embarrasing... Thank you -- Great talk, by way.) I was planing on posting an answer, but it will have to way a few days. Maybe Saturday.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I had meant to include a separate case for $\kappa \leq \omega$, but forgot at the last minute.  Basically, if $\kappa \leq \omega$, then $L_{\kappa}=V_{\kappa}$.  So, if $X \in L_{\kappa}$, then $X \in V_{\kappa}$ and hence $X \subset V_{\lambda}$ for some $\lambda < \kappa$.  Then, $P(X) \subset P(V_{\lambda}) \subset V_{\kappa}=L_{\kappa}$

Comment: Yes, that's right. So I think you've got it.